# What does Worf say when Data sings?

Tags: dialogue, star-trek, star-trek-nemesis

In *Star Trek - Nemesis* Worf says two things during the wedding scene: First he complains that Romulan Ale should be forbidden, and later - when Data sings his song - he says something I never understood. 
From the accompanying movement of burying his head it could mean something like "Oh no, not singing please", but might also sound like an extended burp ...
Actually, it seems that his line is left in the original voice even in the otherwise German dubbed movie.

Comment: Someone watched Pro7 last night, eh? ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek-Nemesis.html):

> WORF 
>   (groans)
>   Ugghhh... **Irving Berlin.**

And watching the [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBT7nUxJpC4#t=0m46s), it sure sounds like it.

(Irving Berlin wrote [Blue Skies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Skies_%281926_song%29), the song Data is singing.)

Comment: Indeed; actually the clip linked makes it sound less-clear than it usually sounds when I catch this on TV. In fact, the only reason I associate this song with Irving Berlin is because of this movie -- a fact that came in handy during pub trivia one night!

Comment: Oh, actually I even understood someting like that, but assumed that *Irving* and/or *Berlin'* would be verb forms ...

Comment: Confirmed by the dvd subtitles.

Comment: Confirmed in the novelisation; *"The rhythm was irresistible-to all except Worf, who raised his head from the table and groaned loudly over the music, "**Ugghhh. Irving Berlin.**""*